# Find all nearby addresses by given address from a Firebase db

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm currently working on a delivery app and my db stored in Firebase:
Every Delivery object contains addresses(strOrigin/strDest).
Beside that, i also have a "Delivery guys" db in Firebase.

it looks like this: [image]

[image]

I want to find all the possible delivery guys from "DeliverUser" ,who arrives to nearby addresses of the delivery.strDest (lets say 20 km distance) : In the example above, there is a delivery-guy that arrive to "Rothschild Boulevard, Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel" (less than 20 km) and there is another delivery-guy who arrives to "Ha-Rotem Street, Herzliya, Israel" - and its also OK (less than 20 km).

The inefficient way to do this would be to retrieve all delivery guys in the db into an arrayList, and then start to to the [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) thing on it.

How to do this efficiently?

Comment: Building an app that does geo-coding and geo-querying is a complex and broad topic, well beyond what we can cover in a single Stack Overflow question/answer. Your best bet to get started is by looking at [Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java), which implements ge-ohashing/geo-querying on top of the Firebase Database.